# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TypeNewsController'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-apicontroller

I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet. Where am I going wrong? I really do not know what to do. I wrote all the details below. I've tried and did not succeed.

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'TypeNewsController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            Bootstrapper.Run();
        }
    }
```

my apicontroller :

```
public class TypeNewsController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ITypeNewsService _typeNewsService;

        public TypeNewsController(ITypeNewsService typeNewsService)
        {
            _typeNewsService = typeNewsService;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public TypeNewsResponse Get([ModelBinder] PageRequest model)
        {
            model = model ?? new PageRequest();
            var output = _typeNewsService.GetTypeNewss().ToList();
            return new TypeNewsResponse
            {
                Page = model.PageIndex,
                Records = model.PageSize,
                Rows = output.ToList(),
                Total = output.Count() / model.PageSize,
            };
        }
    }
```

error :

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TypeNewsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'JuventusNewsSiteApk.Controllers.TypeNewsController' does not have a default constructor
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Bootstrapper class :

```
public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            SetAutofacContainer();
            //Configure AutoMapper
            AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        }

        private static void SetAutofacContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<DatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(NewsRepository).Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(NewsService).Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DefaultFormsAuthentication).Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Authentication"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

            builder.Register(
                c => new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new JuventusNewsApkEntities())))
                .As<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
            IContainer container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
```

**update :**

```
 public class TypeNewsService : ITypeNewsService
    {
        private readonly ITypeNewsRepository _typeNewsRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public TypeNewsService(ITypeNewsRepository typeNewsRepository,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _typeNewsRepository = typeNewsRepository;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        #region ITypeNewsService Member

        public void AddTypeNews(TypeNews typeNews)
        {
            _typeNewsRepository.Add(typeNews);
            SaveTypeNews();
        }

        public void DeleteTypeNews(int id)
        {
            _typeNewsRepository.DeleteById(id);
            SaveTypeNews();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TypeNews> GetTypeNewss()
        {
            var output = _typeNewsRepository.GetAll();
            return output;
        }

        public void SaveTypeNews()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        #endregion

    }

    public interface ITypeNewsService
    {
        void AddTypeNews(TypeNews typeNews);
        void DeleteTypeNews(int id);
        IEnumerable<TypeNews> GetTypeNewss();
        void SaveTypeNews();
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your controller is `WebApi` controller and registration for Autofac differs from MVC registration. WebApi does not use `DependencyResolver`, so you'll need to tell WebApi to use Autofac resolver specifically.

You'll need to add this to your `SetAutofacContainer` code:

```
// Create the depenedency resolver.
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

// Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

See https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration for more info.

Comment: Nice, just beat me to the same answer.

Comment: error : 'Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.BeginScope()'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.'

Comment: i change Autofac.WebApi2 version from  3.3.3 to 3.3.0. it works. thanks

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the reason was that the resolver could not find a mapping. That is, suppose say HomeController has a dependency on IDumb, the resolver could not find a concrete implementation of Dumb which implements IDumb.

In other words the error message

```
**No parameterless constructor defined for this object
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ToDoListT1.WebApp.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor**
```

is completely misleading.

In my case I just resolved by adding a reference to the project of the class Dumb. It should have been something like "No mapping for IDumb could be found.". I am not sure whether the problem is with NInject or MS. Whatever, it took me hours to find this out.

Comment: I've been having the same problem, and I have some unimplemented interfaces, so this looks like it will fix it. Thanks! +1!

Comment: It looks like Web API will show this error if the constructor for an ApiController throws an exception, no matter what it is.  I also had a problem with Ninject, but you can see the same behavior if you just add  `throw new Exception("sadface");` to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Make you sure than you're calling the same call type, I mean, Get, Post, Put, and what kind you have in the controller method.

And do you need to add your valid repository to NijectConfig.cs for the controller.

kernel.Bind<[iRepo]>().To<[Repo]>().InRequestScope();

Answer (score -5):

For controller you should have parameter less constructor. If you want to use parametrized constructor please use code like below.

Pass object of TypeNewsService class

```
private readonly ITypeNewsService _typeNewsService;
public TypeNewsController():this(new TypeNewsService ())
{
} 
public TypeNewsController(ITypeNewsService typeNewsService)
{
   _typeNewsService = typeNewsService;
}
```

Comment: The poster has asked how to 'Inject' an instance into a parameterized constructor. Please read about Dependency Injection. If he had wanted to create a new instance using the the 'new' keyword, he wouldn't need to pass it from the the default constructor to a parameterized constructor in the same class.